# HTTP and HTTPS server at the same time

Tags: esp8266, http

I'm trying to set up a HTTP and HTTPS server at the same time on an ESP8266 NodeMCU V3. The compiler however doesn't accept any other name than `client` otherwise no new clients will be catched. But `client` cannot be used twice and I cannot get it to switch every loop because of the different data-type; `WiFiClient` and `WiFiClientSecure`.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish even possible?

`Sketch.ino`

```cpp
// Configuration
const char* CONFIG_SSID      = "mywifi";
const char* CONFIG_PSK       = "wifipassword";
const int   CONFIG_SERIAL    = 115200;
const int   CONFIG_HTTPPORT  = 80;
const int   CONFIG_HTTPSPORT = 443;

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

// Include libraries
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

// Create webserver object
WiFiServer HTTPserver(CONFIG_HTTPPORT);
WiFiServerSecure HTTPSserver(CONFIG_HTTPSPORT);
static const uint8_t rsakey[] PROGMEM = {
  #include "key.h"
};
static const uint8_t x509[] PROGMEM = {
  #include "x509.h"
};

// Setup instructions
void setup() {

  // Start serial and LED
  Serial.begin(CONFIG_SERIAL);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Starting setup");
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 1);

  // Start WiFi connection
  Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
  Serial.println(CONFIG_SSID);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(CONFIG_SSID, CONFIG_PSK);

  // Wait for WiFi connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(250);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("WiFi connected!");

  // Print WiFi connection information
  Serial.print("  MAC Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());
  Serial.print("  SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  Serial.print("  RSSI: ");
  Serial.print(WiFi.RSSI());
  Serial.println(" dBm");
  Serial.print("  IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print("  Gateway: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.gatewayIP());

  // Start webserver
  Serial.println("Starting webserver...");
  HTTPserver.begin();
  HTTPSserver.setServerKeyAndCert_P(rsakey, sizeof(rsakey), x509, sizeof(x509));
  HTTPSserver.begin();
  Serial.println("Webserver started!");

  // Print webserver information
  Serial.print("  Hostname: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.hostname());
  Serial.print("  HTTP Port: ");
  Serial.println(CONFIG_HTTPPORT);
  Serial.print("  HTTPS Port: ");
  Serial.println(CONFIG_HTTPSPORT);

}

// Loop instructions
void loop() {

  // Wait for new client
  WiFiClient HTTPclient = HTTPserver.available();
  WiFiClientSecure HTTPSclient = HTTPSserver.available();
  if (HTTPclient || HTTPSclient) {
  }

}
```

**UPDATE (2019-06-05):**

I've tried @KIIV's method which works! However it brings a new problem into the equation. HTTPS requests take pretty long te complete, currently about 2 seconds. And it makes the HTTPS request twice for some reason (see log; I made only one request after setup).

`Sketch-updated.ino`

```cpp
// Configuration
const char* CONFIG_SSID      = "mywifi";
const char* CONFIG_PSK       = "wifipassword";
const int   CONFIG_SERIAL    = 115200;
const int   CONFIG_HTTPPORT  = 80;
const int   CONFIG_HTTPSPORT = 443;

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

// Include libraries
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

// Create webserver object
WiFiServer HTTPserver(CONFIG_HTTPPORT);
WiFiServerSecure HTTPSserver(CONFIG_HTTPSPORT);
static const uint8_t rsakey[] PROGMEM = {
  #include "key.h"
};
static const uint8_t x509[] PROGMEM = {
  #include "x509.h"
};

// Setup instructions
void setup() {

  // Start serial and LED
  Serial.begin(CONFIG_SERIAL);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Starting setup");
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 1);

  // Start WiFi connection
  Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
  Serial.println(CONFIG_SSID);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(CONFIG_SSID, CONFIG_PSK);

  // Wait for WiFi connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(250);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("WiFi connected!");

  // Print WiFi connection information
  Serial.print("  MAC Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());
  Serial.print("  SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  Serial.print("  RSSI: ");
  Serial.print(WiFi.RSSI());
  Serial.println(" dBm");
  Serial.print("  IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print("  Gateway: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.gatewayIP());

  // Start webserver
  Serial.println("Starting webserver...");
  HTTPserver.begin();
  HTTPSserver.setServerKeyAndCert_P(rsakey, sizeof(rsakey), x509, sizeof(x509));
  HTTPSserver.begin();
  Serial.println("Webserver started!");

  // Print webserver information
  Serial.print("  Hostname: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.hostname());
  Serial.print("  HTTP Port: ");
  Serial.println(CONFIG_HTTPPORT);
  Serial.print("  HTTPS Port: ");
  Serial.println(CONFIG_HTTPSPORT);

  // Setup complete
  Serial.println("Setup completed");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 0);
  Serial.println();

}

// Loop instructions
void loop() {

  // New wait for new client
  if (HTTPserver.hasClient()) {

    // Set client to HTTP for this loop
    //auto client = HTTPserver.available();
    WiFiClient client = HTTPserver.available();

    // Response
    Serial.println("This is HTTP");
    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    client.println("Content-Type: text/plain");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    client.println("This is HTTP");

  } else if (HTTPSserver.hasClient()) {

    // Set client to HTTP for this loop
    //auto client = HTTPSserver.available();
    WiFiClientSecure client = HTTPSserver.available();

    // Response
    Serial.println("This is HTTP Secure");
    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    client.println("Content-Type: text/plain");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    client.println("This is HTTP Secure");

  }

}
```

`Serial Log`

```cpp
15:59:34.121 -> Starting setup
15:59:34.121 -> Connecting to: mywifi
15:59:34.452 -> .............
15:59:38.205 -> WiFi connected!
15:59:38.205 ->   MAC Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
15:59:38.238 ->   SSID: mywifi
15:59:38.238 ->   RSSI: -21 dBm
15:59:38.238 ->   IP Address: 192.168.1.121
15:59:38.238 ->   Gateway: 192.168.1.1
15:59:38.238 -> Starting webserver...
15:59:38.238 -> Webserver started!
15:59:38.238 ->   Hostname: ESP_XXXXXX
15:59:38.238 ->   HTTP Port: 80
15:59:38.238 ->   HTTPS Port: 443
15:59:38.271 -> Setup completed
15:59:38.271 -> 
16:00:38.069 -> This is HTTP Secure
16:00:38.833 -> This is HTTP Secure
```

Comment: I'd try if there is client awaiting first: `if (HTTPserver.hasClient()) { auto client = HTTPSserver.available(); /* do something; */ }` and the same for HTTPS. (and maybe optimistic_yield(1000) as it's used inside of available so it'll be almost the same

Comment: @KIIV your method works! It however also causes a problem; HTTPS requests take a really long time to complete. Between 5-10 seconds, which also triggers a timeout function (not present in example code). This long time is not happening when trying a sketch which only uses a HTTPS server.